# How to increase, decrease and reset the counter in dynamic web application

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

Here we have counter application to increase, decrease and reset the counter by using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but I can't getting to do how we can increase the counter and decrease the counter and reset the counter.

- When the HTML button element with the id `decreaseBtn` is clicked,
  If the count is odd then decrease the counter value by -1 as shown in the image.
  If the count is even then decrease the counter value by -2 as shown in the image.
- When the HTML button element with the id increaseBtn is clicked,
  If the count is odd then increase the counter value by 10 as shown in the image.
  If the count is even then increase the counter value by 5 as shown in the image.
- When the HTML button element with the id resetBtn is clicked,
  Set counter value as 0.

The Output image is [Counter app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNJO6.gif)

```js
let counterElement = document.getElementById("counterValue");

function onIncrement() {
  let previousCounterValue = counterElement.textContent;
  let updatedCounterValue = parseInt(previousCounterValue) + 1;
  if (updatedCounterValue > 0) {
    counterElement.style.color = "black";
  }
  else if (updatedCounterValue < 0) {
    counterElement.style.color = "black";
  }
  else {
    counterElement.style.color = "black";
  }
  counterElement.textContent = updatedCounterValue;
}

function onDecrement() {
  let previousCounterValue = counterElement.textContent;
  let updatedCounterValue = parseInt(previousCounterValue) - 1;
  if (updatedCounterValue > 0) {
    counterElement.style.color = "black";
  }
  else if (updatedCounterValue < 0) {
    counterElement.style.color = "black";
  }
  else {
    counterElement.style.color = "black";
  }
  counterElement.textContent = updatedCounterValue;
}

function onReset() {
  let counterValue = 0;
  counterElement.textContent = counterValue;
  counterElement.style.color = "black";
}
```

```css
 @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Caveat:wght@400;700&family=Lobster&family=Monoton&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap");

.counter-value {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.button {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #0967d2;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-width: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
    <p id="counterValue" class="counter-value">0</p>
    <button id="decreaseBtn" class="button" onclick="onDecrement()">DECREASE</button>
    <button id="resetBtn" class="button" onclick="onReset()">RESET</button>
    <button id="increaseBtn" class="button" onclick="onIncrement()">INCREASE</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected Output is
[Counter app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59emy.gif)

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Comment: Javascript code sir

Comment: I meant what is the exact bug that you are facing

Comment: Please once refer the output image and help me sir

Comment: When the HTML button element with the id increaseBtn is clicked, If the count is odd then increase the counter value by 10 . If the count is even then increase the counter value by 5. This is not getting how to implement this logic in code sir

Comment: When the HTML button element with the id decreaseBtn is clicked, If the count is odd then decrease the counter value by -1. If the count is even then decrease the counter value by -2. This is not getting how to implement this logic in code sir

Comment: Its easy, just see if the number is divisible by 2 to find out if its odd or even, however good luck with this in the negatives.

Comment: Yeah try what @michaelMano suggested.

Comment: `if (Math.abs(previousNumber) % 2 == 0) { // even } else { // odd }` The reason for Math.abs is because you are working with negative numbers, And you cant divide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I am new to js so may not be best solution.

```js
let count = 0;
const counter = document.getElementById("counterValue");

function isEven(num) {
    return num % 2 ? false : true;
}

function onDecrement() {
    if (isEven(count)) {
        count = count - 2;
    } else {
        count = count - 1;
    }
    counter.textContent = count;
}

function onReset() {
    count = 0;
    counter.textContent = count;
}

function onIncrement() {
    if (isEven(count)) {
        count = count + 5;
    } else {
        count = count + 10;
    }
    counter.textContent = count;
}
```

```css
.counter-value {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.button {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #0967d2;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
  <p id="counterValue" class="counter-value">0</p>
  <button id="decreaseBtn" class="button" onclick="onDecrement()">DECREASE</button>
  <button id="resetBtn" class="button" onclick="onReset()">RESET</button>
  <button id="increaseBtn" class="button" onclick="onIncrement()">INCREASE</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much  @Rutvik Padhiyar

Comment: It's a best solution

Answer (score 0):

The other users in the comments have explained about [how to check whether the count is odd or even](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).

I wanted to add an answer that approaches the code from a slightly different angle, and which I often find very useful.

Instead of picking up the `textContent` of the counter element and parsing it to a number we maintain one number variable.

We give each button [a data-type attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), and a button container *one* handler function that is called immeditately.

The reason for this is so we can use a technique called [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) - a function returned from another function but maintains references to the variables that were declared *before* it was returned.

1. We can intitialise `count`.
2. We return the closure.
3. When any button is clicked the event bubbles up the DOM and is captured by the listener in the container (this is called [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/).
4. We check the data type. We update `count` based on the type and whether the count is odd or even.
5. Finally we update the counter element text.

```js
// Cache the elements
const counterElement = document.querySelector('#counterValue');
const container = document.querySelector('#container');

// Add a listener to the container
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

// Small function to check whether the
// count is odd or even
function isEven(count) {
  return count % 2 === 0;
}

// Initialise the count variable
function handleClick(count = 0) {

  // Return a new function (the closure)
  // as the function that will be called when
  // the buttons are clicked
  return function(e) {

    // Get the button type from the clicked button
    const { type } = e.target.dataset;

    // Now just use `switch` to update the count
    switch(type) {
      case 'decrease': {
        if (isEven(count)) {
          count = count - 2;
        } else {
          count = count - 1;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 'increase': {
        if (isEven(count)) {
          count = count + 5;
        } else {
          count = count + 10;
        }
        break;
      }
      default:
      case 'reset': count = 0; break;
    }

    // Finally update the counter element
    counterElement.textContent = count;
  }
}
```

```css
.counter-value {font-size: 36px; font-weight: 900; }
.button {color: #ffffff; background-color: #0967d2; font-size: 14px; border-width: 0; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<p id="counterValue" class="counter-value">0</p>
<div id="container">
  <button data-type="decrease" class="button">DECREASE</button>
  <button data-type="reset" class="button">RESET</button>
  <button data-type="increase" class="button">INCREASE</button>
</div>
```