# Trying to disable and later enable a button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disable the "decrease" when the counter goes below 0 and re-enable it, when the counter goes up.

But when I press the "increase" button the "decrease" button stays disable.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById('count')
let decreaseEl = document.getElementById('decrease')
let resetEl = document.getElementById('reset')
let increaseEl = document.getElementById('increase')
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save")
let savedEl = document.getElementById('savedCount')
let message = "Invalid Value";
let invalid = false

let countNo = 0;

decreaseEl.addEventListener('click', function(){
    countNo--;
    if(countNo < 0){
        countEl.textContent = message;
        invalid = true
        decreaseEl.disabled = true;
    }else{
    countEl.textContent = countNo;
    invalid = false
    if(invalid = false){
    decreaseEl.disabled = false;
    }
    }
})
resetEl.addEventListener('click', function(){
    countEl.textContent = 0;
    countNo = 0;
    savedEl.textContent = "Counts:";
})
increaseEl.addEventListener('click',function(){
    countNo++;
    countEl.textContent = countNo;
    invalid = false
})
saveEl.addEventListener('click',function(){
    if(invalid == true){
        savedEl.textContent += "";
    }else{
    savedEl.textContent += " " + countNo + "-";
    countNo = 0;
    countEl.textContent = 0;
    }
    
})
```

Comment: Please update the snippet with relevant HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

I would expect something like this:

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById('count')
let decreaseEl = document.getElementById('decrease')
let resetEl = document.getElementById('reset')
let increaseEl = document.getElementById('increase')
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save")
let savedEl = document.getElementById('savedCount')

let message = "Invalid Value";
let invalid = false

let countNo = 0;



decreaseEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  countNo--;
  const neg = countNo < 0;
  countEl.textContent = neg ? message : countNo;
  decreaseEl.disabled = neg;
  if (neg) setTimeout(function() {
    countNo = 0;
    countEl.textContent = countNo
  }, 2000); // optional
})

resetEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  countEl.textContent = 0;
  countNo = 0;
  savedEl.textContent = "Counts:";
})
increaseEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  countNo++;
  countEl.textContent = countNo;
  decreaseEl.disabled = countNo <= 0;
  invalid = false
})
```

```html
<span id="count">0</span>
<button id="increase">Increase</button>
<button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<span id="savedCount">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are added event listener on the button, you are disabling and undisabling the button inside the event listener.

You should do something like this:

```
increaseEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    countNo++;
    countEl.textContent = countNo;
    invalid = false;

    if (countNo > 0) {
        decreaseEl.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `increaseEl.addEventListener` add `if(countNo=>0) decreaseEl.disabled = false;`

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById('count')
let decreaseEl = document.getElementById('decrease')
let resetEl = document.getElementById('reset')
let increaseEl = document.getElementById('increase')

let message = "Invalid Value";
let invalid = false

let countNo = 0;


decreaseEl.addEventListener('click', function(){
    countNo--;
    if(countNo <0){
        countEl.textContent = message;
        invalid = true
        decreaseEl.disabled = true;
    }else{
    countEl.textContent = countNo;
    invalid = false
    if(invalid = false){
    decreaseEl.disabled = false;
    }
    }
})

increaseEl.addEventListener('click',function(){
    countNo++;
    if(countNo=>0) decreaseEl.disabled = false;
    countEl.textContent = countNo;
    invalid = false
})
```

```html
<button id="count">0</button>
<button id="increase">Increase</button>
<button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have your answer as to *why* your doesn't work you may find this example useful/interesting. It's based from code I wrote as [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69173030/1377002) a couple of days ago.

All of the information about *how* it works is in that link, but basically it provides you with a way to handle the buttons from one listener (on the container), and there's no need for a global `count` variable.

```js
// Cache the elements
const counterElement = document.querySelector('#counterValue');
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const decrease = document.querySelector('button[data-type="decrease"]');

// Add a listener to the container
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick(), false);

// Initialise the count variable
function handleClick(count = 0) {

  // Return a new function (the closure)
  // as the function that will be called when
  // the buttons are clicked
  return function(e) {

    // Get the button type from the clicked button
    const { type } = e.target.dataset;

    if (type === 'decrease') --count;

    if (type === 'increase') {
      
      // If the decrease button is disabled
      // re-enable it
      if (decrease.disabled) {
        decrease.disabled = false;
      }
      ++count;
    }

    // Disable the decrease button if it's zero
    if (count === 0) decrease.disabled = true;

    counterElement.textContent = count;

  }

}
```

```css
.counter-value {font-size: 36px; font-weight: 900; }
.button {color: #ffffff; background-color: #0967d2; font-size: 14px; border-width: 0; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;}
button { cursor: pointer; }
button:disabled { opacity: 30%; cursor: default;}
```

```html
<p id="counterValue" class="counter-value">0</p>
<div id="container">
  <button data-type="decrease" class="button" disabled>DECREASE</button>
  <button data-type="increase" class="button">INCREASE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are having curretly is, you are settting the `disabled` status of your `#decrease` button onli inside the click event of `#decrease` button. This works in setting the `disabled` status of button to true.

You are setting the disabled status of the button to false inside the else statement of `countNo < 0` inside the click event of `#decrease` button. Does this have any impact on your functionality? NO!!!. Why? Because when the number is negative, the button will be `disabled` and the click event wont trigger and the `disable` status wont be reset to false.

The enabling of the button should be handled in the `#increase` button click event instead. You can directly rest the disabled status to false if the button is disabled. Because the count wont go negative inside this function.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById('count')
let decreaseEl = document.getElementById('decrease')
let resetEl = document.getElementById('reset')
let increaseEl = document.getElementById('increase')
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save")
let savedEl = document.getElementById('savedCount')
let message = "Invalid Value";
let invalid = false

let countNo = 0;

decreaseEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
  countNo--;
  if (countNo < 0) {
    countEl.textContent = message;
    invalid = true
    decreaseEl.disabled = true;
  } else {
    countEl.textContent = countNo;
    invalid = false
    // This doesnot have any impact
    // if (invalid = false) {
    //   decreaseEl.disabled = false;
    // }
  }
})
resetEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
  countEl.textContent = 0;
  countNo = 0;
  savedEl.textContent = "Counts:";
})
increaseEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
  countNo++;
  countEl.textContent = countNo;
  invalid = false
  if (decreaseEl.disabled) {
    decreaseEl.disabled = !decreaseEl.disabled;
  }
})
saveEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (invalid == true) {
    savedEl.textContent += "";
  } else {
    savedEl.textContent += " " + countNo + "-";
    countNo = 0;
    countEl.textContent = 0;
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="count">0</button>
<button id="increase">Increase</button>
<button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<p id="savedCount"></p>
```